# Buchi's conditional proof of the non-existence of finite algorithm to decide solubility of system of diagonal quadratic form equations in integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

I am doing some literature review regarding [Buchi's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCchi%27s_problem). In particular, I am reading the relevant section in this survey paper by Mazur ([Questions of Decidability and Undecidability in Number Theory](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2275395?seq=6)) where it is stated that Buchi proved that there is no finite algorithm which decides the solubility of an arbitrary system of diagonal quadratic form equations

$$A \begin{bmatrix} x_1^2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n^2 \end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{b},$$

where $A \in M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{Z}^m$ (Mazur called this *Buchi's conjecture*), provided that the following statement, known as Buchi's problem (see the Wikipedia page above), holds: there exists a positive integer $m_0$ such that if $x_1^2, \cdots, x_n^2$ is a sequence of squares satisfying

$$\displaystyle x_{j+2}^2 - 2 x_{j+1}^2 + x_j^2 = 2$$

for $j = 1, \cdots, n-2$, then either $n \leq m_0$ or there exists an integer $x$ such that $x_i = x + i$ for $i = 1, \cdots, n$.

Mazur had cited Buchi's collected works. Unfortunately, I cannot access this from where I am. Does anyone know of an original reference where Buchi proved this implication?

Comment: Xavier Vidaux has several papers that mention Buchi, maybe one of them gives the citation you want. See https://www2.udec.cl/~xvidaux/publi.html

Comment: Find anything helpful at Vidaux' site? If not, you could try writing to him. I suppose it's possible Buchi never formally published a proof.

Comment: Not interested?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hi, I haven't had much chance to look during the holidays. I will take a look in the next few days. Thanks for the suggestion!